# Navigation in Caliburn.Micro - how to replace the whole window

Tags: navigation, caliburn.micro

I have read some articles referring how navigation work with `Screen` and `Conductor<T>` in **Caliburn.Micro**, but they doesn't seem to match my requirement.

My WPF application has 3 views:

1. When user starts the application, a **welcome screen** is displayed, and the application would do some startup work in background.
2. When application finishes startup process, it navigates to a **list view**.
3. When user clicks an item in **list view**, it enters a **detail view**

However, when navigating between different views, I need the **whole window** to be replaced, it seems `Conductor<T>` works when there is a `ContentControl` in the view and replaces **part** of the view, now I need the previous view to be **destroyed** and a new view replaces it, **no ContentControl, no MDI application**, so what do I miss to implement this simple navigation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't this be a `ShellViewModel`/`ShellView` with a `ContentControl` that consumes the entire shell Window? Alternatively, you could look at the [WindowManager](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager) class provided with Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: This is one apporach i worked through, but when I navigate from **list view** to **detail view**, I have to call a `Navigate` method from `ShellViewModel`, this introduces a dependency between `ListViewModel` and `ShellViewModel`, the result is each of my ViewModel depends on the `ShellViewModel` and this looks not nice :(, so I'm wondering if there is a more free way to navigate between views, I would give `WindowManager` a try, thanks

Comment: Your list view model/detail view model doesn't need to have a dependency on the shell view model. For inter-viewmodel communication you can either use standard .NET events (subscribe to an event on your list view model from your shell view model) or use Caliburn.Micro's event aggregator.